# Background Image in Latex not transparent

Tags: backgrounds

I am adding a background image to my document. I have used my code before, and everything worked fine. However, I recently reopened and recompiled the code, and now the image is not transparent on the first page. It is correct throughout the rest of the document, but the first page has no transparency. I haven't changed the code from when it was working before to now. Below is the code.

```
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{
scale=1,
color=myblack,
opacity=0.1,
angle=0,
contents={%
  \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{logo-02}
  }%
}
\begin{document}
Some Text
\end{document}
```

For reference, [this is what it looked like when I first created the document in July](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/59e631f97131a56479b866d8/t/627ef9c391c91a1f620e4647/1652488646077/Correlation+and+Regression.pdf). However, when I reopened the document and complied the code again, with no changes, [it is now presenting like this](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/59e631f97131a56479b866d8/t/637653e80166cd6ff85f9588/1668699113170/Correlation+and+Regression+1.pdf).

Comment: your example can't be tested. It is incomplete, uses undefined colors and a picture we don't have.

Comment: Welcome! What format is `logo-02`? I tried to complete the example with a standard preamble and I see the background.

Comment: I have the example outputs. I have the picture in both a png and jpg format, and have tried using both. However, it was originally created with the png file.

Comment: Meantime the package background has changed?